# Can't find context in makeText() while making a Toast

Tags: android, toast, mobile-development

This is my code:

```
public class CustomDialog extends DialogFragment {
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder myDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    myDialogBuilder.setTitle("Get Ready To Rumble!");
    myDialogBuilder.setMessage("Do you wanna rumble?!");
    myDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(. this, "Let's Rumble!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
    )

    return myDialogBuilder.create();


}
```

}

There seems to be an error of the content at the line :

```
Toast.makeText(CustomDialog.this, "Let's Rumble!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I've tried just typing "this", "DialogFragment.this"...
Can't seem to find out the problem.

Hope you guys can help me, sorry for the long code.

Comment: Use `getActivity()` instead of `CustomDialog.this`

Comment: Can't work, got red lines all over the setPositiveButton() method.

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this

```
Toast.makeText(CustomDialog.this.getActivity(), "Let's Rumble!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Can't work, got red lines all over the setPositiveButton() method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
Dialog mainDialog  = (Dialog) dialog;
Context context = mainDialog.getContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

there are a couple of ways to make this work
easiest is to call this instead

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

another is to pass the context as dialog constructor argument along any other data but don't forget to create a default noarg one aswell

```
public class CustomDialog extends DialogFragment {

private Context context;

public CustomDialog(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

public CustomDialog(){}

//you may get a warning but it works
```

}

Answer (score 0):

When working in fragments using `getActivity()` returns the Activity the Fragment is currently associated with.

If you are working in a normal activity passing context or `getApplicationContext()` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this , just pass context of you activity while creating CustomDialog class object :

```
public class CustomDialog extends DialogFragment {

private Context context;

public CustomDialog(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}
public CustomDialog(){ } //default no arg constructor 

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder myDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    myDialogBuilder.setTitle("Get Ready To Rumble!");
    myDialogBuilder.setMessage("Do you wanna rumble?!");
    myDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Let's Rumble!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
    )

    return myDialogBuilder.create();


}
```